# subprocess problems with sudo,ctrl+c and pipes

Tags: linux, python-2.7, subprocess, pipe, sudo

I need to run an external `C_program` using `subprocess` from a python script.

Here is the tricky parts:

1. the external program needs to run with super user privileges, and thus I need to ask the user to input his password to make sure he is allowed to run the program.
2. The external program might run for extremely long time (sometimes days) and the user might need to terminate it manually using `CTRL+C`
3. The output of the `C_program` should be printed to the screen thus the `stdout` should be piped to the `subprocess`.

this is what I've tried doing:

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(c_program, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    #needs sudo password to run this program
    proc.communicate(getpass.getpass())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "you stopped c_program, script will now go on..."
#do other things
```

unfortunately, this will cause two problems which I cannot seem to be able to fix:

1. pressing `CTRL+C` while `c_program` is being executed will do absolutly nothing (not only won't it stop the execution of `c_program` or even the python script itself, it is just ignored...)
2. In case the script does finish its run, the terminal starts behaving... it will not display what the user is typing in but it does respond to it (for example, typing `ls -l` will not be displayed on the screen, but, after pressing enter, the output of the command will be printed to the screen)

I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu

Please help :)

Comment: Here's [a python script that runs a C program (`python`) that can be interrupted by `Ctrl+C` and that doesn't corrupt terminal](https://gist.github.com/a16c3321ec8e5fbb8066). Could you provide a complete minimal code example that shows the issues?

Comment: nothing to add other than adding the c_program itself (and it happens with most C programs, so it's not gonna help), the remaining code in the script parses the output.

Comment: if it happens with most C programs; it should be easy for you to create the example, shouldn't it? [My example](https://gist.github.com/a16c3321ec8e5fbb8066) demonstrates that `Ctrl+C` works at least for some programs.

Comment: I'm trying to run zmap [link](www.zmap.io) so if you change `c_program` to `zmap` you'll get exactly my problem

Comment: are you sure that scanning the ENTIRE IPv4 address space is the only way to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I don't actually scan the whole IPv4 but use smaller subnets, but this does reproduce the problem (so does using a different program that consumes high CPU and opens multiple sockets)